# Image Texture Node Output

Tags: image

Can someone kindly explain the difference between color and alpha output from the image texture node? I can't really find any useful information in understanding the difference between these two. Thank You So Much.

Comment: Well explained in the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html#outputs Does this help? What else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpha datas are useful when you want to give transparency to an area of your material.

In the case of the *Image Texture Alpha* output, let say you have a PNG with a transparent background (0% alpha). Plug the *Image Texture's Alpha* output into the *Alpha* socket of the *Principled* (or into the *Factor* of a *Mix Shader* between a *Diffuse* and a *Transparent* shader), the alpha of your image will be recognized as the area that needs to be transparent.

[image]

Comment: Thank You So Much :D